# how to get plain phone numbers from formatted string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have phone numbers like
(123)-456-7890
123-456-7890
123 - 456 - 7890

But i need to convert these into 1234567890. how can I do that in Javascript ?

Comment: Can you post your attempts so far please?...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var onlyNums = "(123)-456-7890".replace(/[^0-9]/g,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just strip out unwanted characters by replace. You can still use regex if you need:

```
numbers = phoneNumber.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
```

---

**Edit:** If you are interested in capturing the parts of the number, you can use `.match()`:

```
parts = phoneNumber.match(/(\d{3}).*?(\d{3}).*?(\d{4})/);
```

And `parts` will be an array of 4 items:

- `parts[0]` - The captured string, from the first number to the last.
- `parts[1]` - The area code (3 digits as a string)
- `parts[2]` - The prefix (3 digits as a string)
- `parts[3]` - The last 4 digits as a string.

You can then do what you need to like put them into a string with:

```
parts.shift();
number = parts.join('');
```

Which will also give you the same answer.

Comment: I was writing my answer before you posted yours. There's plenty of ways to solve OP's question. No need to downvote for that.